# Printing private messages

Tags: facebook

How do I print a private message thread from Facebook?  The answers I've seen pertain only to comment threads posted, not private messaging.

Answer (score 1):

Without some sort of browser extension, this isn't possible to do via facebook.com or messenger.com.